# C++ Freetype advance X problem

Tags: opengl, c++, text

I'm currently working on a font-rendering system for my OpenGL based engine. 
I sure got something to work, but the only thing I still have problems with, is the horizontal advance!

[image: example]

This is what it spits out, obviously not correct. If I understood correct from the documentation and some other threads, this is the procedure to draw a string:

1. set current drawing position to (0, 0)
2. draw first character
3. move drawing position in the x for advance.x
4. draw second character
5. move drawing position in the x for next face->glyph->advance.x
6. ... repeat

Is that correct? If not, what am I doing wrong?
I think its worth to say that I render every character as a texture!

Comment: It looks like you when you draw a letter, you then move the x by the next letter's width instead of the one you just drawn

Comment: Well that did it kind of. I should move my cursor after drawing the current one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bálint stated, the advance is for the next char. So just moving the cursor after drawing the current one solved it!

Comment: You should accept this answer.